# Append arrays and lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

For example, if the entered input is:

```
1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8
```

we should manipulate it to

```
1 2 3|4 5 6|7 8
```

Another example:

```
7 | 4 5|1 0| 2 5 |3
```

we should manipulate it to

```
7|4 5|1 0|2 5|3
```

This is my idea because I want to exchange some of the subarrays (7; 4 5; 1 0; 2 5; 3).

I'm not sure that this code is working and it can be the base of I want to do but I must upload it for you to see my work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> arrays = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var element in arrays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("element: " + element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your input by "|" first and then by space. After this, you can reassemble your input with [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__). Try this code:

```
var input = "1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8";
var result = string.Join("|", input.Split('|')
  .Select(part => string.Join(" ", 
    part.Trim().Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))));

// now result is "1 2 3|4 5 6|7 8"
```

Answer (score 2):

This could do this with a simple regular expression:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s?\|\s?", "|");
```

This will match any (optional) white space character, followed by a `|` character, followed by an (optional) white space character and replace it with a single `|` character.

Alternatively, if you need to potentially strip out multiple spaces around the `|`, replace the zero-or-one quantifiers (`?`) with zero-or-more quantifiers (`*`):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*\|\s*", "|");
```

To also deal with multiple spaces between numbers (not just around `|` characters), I'd recommend something like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*([\s|])\s*", "$1")
```

This will match any occurrence of zero or more white space characters, followed by either a white space character or a `|` character (captured in group `1`), followed by zero or more white space characters and replace it with whatever was captured in group `1`.